# Game stops working when restart button clicked

Tags: ios, swift

I have just started programming this past week and have been trying to make a simple game app for IOS. Everything had worked properly regarding what I want the game to be doing when playing it. However, after I lose and get taken to my end scene, when I click the restart button, the app appears to take me back to the game scene but instead opens up a dark brown screen and just stays there for a few seconds before going back to the end scene. Then, if I click the restart button again after being taken back to the end scene, it repeats.

It also appears that how long the brown screen lasts is dependent on the sharkTimer with the fastest time interval. So if the fastest on is generating a shark every half a second, the brown screen lasts for half a second before transferring to the end scene.

The game is really simple as the character is a fish that swims up and down and the goal of the game to eat little things called food and to avoid other things called sharks that swim toward you.

Here is a link to my project:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z8o3iunz9rng6na/AACDGGOTR-QhqbQc402y4sgRa?dl=0

This is what I've got so far in my GameScene.swift file:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

struct physicsCategory
{
    static let shark: UInt32 = 1
    static let food: UInt32 = 2
    static let fish: UInt32 = 3
}


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
{
    var score = Int()
    var scoreLabel = UILabel()
    var fish = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fish1 copy.png")
    var shark = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shark1 copy.png")
    var food = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fish game point copy.png")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 117/255.0, green: 208/255.0, blue: 224/255.0, alpha: 1.0)


        fish.setScale(0.15)
        fish.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.1, self.frame.size.height * 0.5)
        fish.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(35, 40))
        fish.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        fish.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.fish
        fish.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.shark
        fish.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.food
        fish.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

        self.addChild(fish)


        var sharkTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnShark"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        var sharkTimer2 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.33, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnShark"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        var sharkTimer3 = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.79, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnShark"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        var foodTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnFood"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.1, blue: 0.1, alpha: 0.3)
        scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        self.view?.addSubview(scoreLabel)

    }


    func SpawnShark()
    {
        var shark = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shark1 copy.png")
        shark.setScale(0.33)

        var MinValue = self.size.height - self.size.height
        var MaxValue = self.size.height
        var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
        shark.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width  , y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)))

        let action = SKAction.moveToX(-70, duration: 3.0)
        shark.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        shark.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        shark.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(100, 20))
        shark.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        shark.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.shark
        shark.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.fish
        shark.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

        self.addChild(shark)
    }


    func SpawnFood()
    {
        var food = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "fish game point copy.png")
        food.setScale(0.1)

        var MinValue = self.size.height - self.size.height + 10
        var MaxValue = self.size.height - 10
        var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)
        food.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width  , y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)))

        let action = SKAction.moveToX(-70, duration: 5.0)
        food.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))
        let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        food.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))

        food.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(10, 10))
        food.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        food.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.food
        food.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.fish
        food.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

        self.addChild(food)
    }


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact)
    {
        var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fish) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.food) ||
            (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.food) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fish)
        {
            CollisionWithFood(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, food: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }

        else if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.shark) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fish) ||
        (firstBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.fish) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask == physicsCategory.shark)
        {
            CollisionWithFish(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, fish: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }
    }


    func CollisionWithFood(fish: SKSpriteNode, food: SKSpriteNode)
    {
        food.removeFromParent()
        score++

        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }


    func CollisionWithFish(shark: SKSpriteNode, fish: SKSpriteNode)
    {
        fish.removeFromParent()
        scoreLabel.removeFromSuperview()
        self.view?.presentScene(EndScene())
        self.view?.presentScene(EndScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(1.0))

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
    {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches
        {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            fish.position.y = location.y

        }
    }


    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        for touch: AnyObject in touches
        {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            fish.position.y = location.y

        }

    }


    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
    {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    }
}
```

My second file called EndScene.swift is where the program goes to if the shark gets you and the game ends. Its a white screen with a little restart button in the upper middle of the screen that when you press it, should take you back to the game scene, but instead takes you to a dark brown one.

Here is my EndScene.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class EndScene: SKScene
{
    var restartButton: UIButton!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
    {
        scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        restartButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 30))
        restartButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.width / 7)


        restartButton.setTitle("Restart", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        restartButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        restartButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Restart"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view?.addSubview(restartButton)

    }

    func Restart()
    {

        self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.3))
        restartButton.removeFromSuperview()
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `self.view` to `GameScene` init when presenting the scene

```
func Restart()
{
    self.view?.presentScene(GameScene(size: view.frame.size), transition: SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.3))
    restartButton.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: When I try that, it gives me the error, "could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments.

Comment: Check the answer now, I forgot to add size instead of view

Comment: Thanks, that made it work! However, it seemed to have created another problem. After clicking the restart button, it now sends it back to my game scene, but it appears to be zoomed in as the objects are larger. Also, the fps is affected more after clicking the restart button the first time as less objects cause the fps to drop more.